# How to unit-test `Contract` whose state contains `StatePointer`

Tags: corda

When I test the a `Contract` whose `ContractState` has a `LinearPointer` to another state, the log first shows the warning

```
[WARN] 15:13:20,131 [Test worker] transactions.TransactionBuilder. - WARNING: You must pass in a ServiceHub reference to TransactionBuilder to resolve state pointers outside of flows. If you are writing a unit test then pass in a MockServices instance.
```

and of course the test failed, because the `LedgerTransaction` verified by the `Contract` do not have the pointed-to state resolved.

So I followed the instruction and passed the `MockService` to the `TransactionBuilder`. But the following error occured:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockServices.getVaultService(MockServices.kt:438)
    at net.corda.core.contracts.LinearPointer.resolve(StatePointer.kt:183)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.resolveStatePointers(TransactionBuilder.kt:738)
    at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.addOutputState(TransactionBuilder.kt:804)
```

When I dug into the source code, I found that `MockService`'s `vaultService` can not be retrieved:

```
override val vaultService: VaultService get() = throw UnsupportedOperationException()
```

So, how am I supposed to test this kind of `Contract` whose verification involves resolving states referenced by `StatePointer`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a solution struck me when I am writing the question:

Mannually add the pointed-to state to the transaction as a reference state

Comment: There is a problem with this approach as it's not an accurate representation of what your transaction will actually look like because you likely don't require the pointed-to linear state to be referenced in your transaction; if you did mandate that the state should be referenced, then the contract should fail on not finding the referenced state. A better solution would be to test this as part of your workflow tests, rather than your contract tests, as workflow tests do have access to a mocked `VaultService` implementation.

Comment: Side note: When state pointers were first implemented by R3, it was mandatory that pointed-to states were referenced in the same transaction to ensure that there were no pointers to stale/consumed data. This caused a bug with `StaticPointer` because if the pointed-to state had already been consumed, the notary wouldn't sign the transaction upon seeing a stale referenced state, therefore the state implementing a `StaticPointer` was forever locked and could not be evolved/transitioned. I worked with R3 on fixing this, and there is now a Boolean flag to make referenced states optional.

Comment: @MatthewLayton thanks for your comments. Well, in my case, the contract **does** check the pointed-to state, so not a terrible expedient... I have encountered this problem before and used the way you suggested (i.e., test the contract in workflow tests). However, I just don't want to "inflate" the testing on the flow's part whose main purpose (i think) is to test the smart contract's "communication logic" rather that "contract logic".

Comment: I think there is still some problem about "resolving `StatePointer`". It seems the api does not expose the switch to turn on or off the Boolean flag. see this [issue](https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/6883)

Comment: Good point with respect to checking in the contract rather than the workflow, however if your contract is checking that the state is referenced, then I don't think you need to test whether or not you can resolve it from the vault (it's not possible to reference it from the transaction without it being in the vault in the first place). To your second point with respect to resolving state pointers, I've commented on that GitHub issue: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/6883#issuecomment-901894501

Comment: @MatthewLayton thanks again for your reply. I need to clarify that my contract **uses the data** in the pointed-to state, so the pointed-to state **has to be** somehow resolved and included in the transation. In other words, the contract is not "checking that the state is referenced", but "checking the state that is referenced". I'm not "testing whether or not I can resolve the referenced state from the vault" - I don't care how the state is resolved, as long as the framework includes it in my transaction so that the contract verification code can use the data in it.